# How Can I Remove Tag before taking a Screenshot or PDF in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to remove a tag before taking a screenshot or generating a PDF.

Is there any way can lead to this?

I've tried to add `page.addScriptTag(options)` and `page.addStyleTag(options)`.

I get an error like:

```
Error when rendering page: TypeError: page.addStyleTag is not a function
```

Comment: which puppeteer version you are using?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to remove the element from within the Page DOM Environment:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let example = document.querySelector('#example');

  example.parentNode.removeChild(example);
});

await page.screenshot({
  path: 'screenshot.png',
});
```